# Wordpress: checkboxes in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I currently have this code...

```
    $wpdb->update( 
        $table_name_employee, 
        array( 
            'ID' => $_POST["user"], 
            'Role' => $_POST["Role"], 
            'Seniority' => $_POST["Seniority"], 
            'Payroll' => $_POST["Payroll"], 
            'ReportTo' => $_POST["ReportTo"], 
            'Tasks' => $_POST["Tasks"], 
        ), 
        array( 
            'ID' => $_POST["user"], 
        ) 
    );
```

The value of `$_POST["Tasks"]` is an array and not a string. It is derived from checkbox code...

```
...
<input type=checkbox name="Tasks[]" value="38"> Task 38
<input type=checkbox name="Tasks[]" value="39"> Task 39
<input type=checkbox name="Tasks[]" value="40"> Task 40
... many more
```

If I change `Tasks[]` to `Task` I only check the value of one checkbox. If I leave it as `Tasks[]` the value is passed as an array but the `$wpdb->update()` command above fails with this error:

```
Warning: mb_check_encoding() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/gj/public_html/matrix/bg/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2378

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/gj/public_html/matrix/bg/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1094
```

My question is: How do I correctly modify the `$wpdb->update()` above considering `$_POST["Tasks"]` is an array? Any searches I have made have been unsuccessful in showing a similar scenario.

Comment: This is the normal result for a checkbox post in PHP. You can use implode to serialize your array in string. Or you have to create an other table to store each checkbox value.

Comment: @VincentDecaux successfully pointed out my brain fart and the problem was solved by simply entering the code shown in my answer.

Comment: I would not use implode but it is a way. You also could look at [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or  [maybe_serialize()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize)

Answer (score 0):

Vincent Decaux pointed out my brain fart and adding this code before the `$wpdb->update()` did the trick...

```
    if (isset($_POST['Tasks']))
    {
        $_POST['Tasks']=implode("|", $_POST['Tasks']);
    }
```